# mdDialog won't show templateUrl

Tags: angularjs, servicenow, angularjs-material, mddialog, ng-template

Our team is using mdDialog to pull up a modal that allows a user to edit answers to a questionnaire.

```
    $scope.editQuestionFnct = function(val){
        $scope.editWidget = {};
        //alert(val);
        spUtil.get("gateway_questionnaire_widget", {//call new instance of this widget
            //sys_id: $scope.params.refID,
            task_id: $scope.data.task_id,
            quest_id: val,
            request: 'edit',
            taskTable: $scope.data.task_table,
            questionnaire_table: $scope.params.questionnaireTable,
            serviceID: $scope.params.serviceID,
            refID: $scope.params.refID,
            taskCompleted: false,
            editRequest: true
        }).then(function(response) {
            $scope.editWidget = response;//var to hold widget response to display in modal
            $scope.showPrerenderedDialog('#editQuestion');
        });
    }

    $scope.showPrerenderedDialog = function(name) {
        $mdDialog.show({
            templateUrl: name,
            parent: angular.element(document.body),
            clickOutsideToClose:true
        });
    };

    $scope.closeDialog = function($scope){  //closes angular dialog window
        $mdDialog.hide($scope);
    }

    $scope.closeSummDialog = function($scope){  //closes angular dialog window
        $mdDialog.hide($scope);
    }

<script type="text/ng-template" id="editQuestion">
      <div class="md-dialog-container" >
        <md-dialog style="background-color: #ffffff;" aria-label="edit dialog">
          <md-toolbar style="background-color: #022C68; width: 100%;">
            <h1 class="md-toolbar-tools" style="color: #ffffff;">Edit Response</h1>
          </md-toolbar> 
          <md-dialog-content style="background-color: #ffffff;">
            <div id="editQuestDiv" style="min-width: 700px;">
              <sp-widget widget="editWidget"></sp-widget>
            </div>
          </md-dialog-content>
          <md-dialog-actions layout="row">
            <span flex></span>
            <md-button ng-click="closeDialog()" style="background-color: #022C68; color: #ffffff;">
              Close
            </md-button>
          </md-dialog-actions>
        </md-dialog>
      </div>
    </script>
```

We are experiencing two problems with the above code:

First, instead of using templateUrl, we were using contentElement, which worked.  Using contentElement pulled up a modal with the question that required editing.  However, when a user clicks out of that first click, and clicks on another question, the same question that appeared in the first click shows up.  Every click afterwards will only pull up the question from the first click.

After doing some reading, we decided to try and use templateUrl instead, but using that above opens up a modal with nothing in it:

[image]

Can someone explain what we're doing wrong?  Are we doing something wrong with contentElement where only the question from the first click persists?  If we were to use templateUrl, why isn't our modal showing up?

Thanks!

Comment: I believe `templateUrl` requires a path to an .html file that will be compiled and shown. You appear to be passing in a query selector for an element. As for `contentElement`, the [docs](https://material.angularjs.org/HEAD/api/service/$mdDialog) say: "Pre-rendered dialogs will be not linked to any scope and will not instantiate any new controller.
You can manually link the elements to a scope or instantiate a controller from the template (ng-controller)". Did you do either of those?

Comment: Hi Lex, thanks for your reply!  No I don't believe any of us did that.  We're all pretty new to angular and even newer to angularjs material...will try to locate an example of how to do this and see if that works.  Thanks!